# How can i know user is active in winform scenario?

Tags: winforms, logout

The requirement is that if user hasn't clicked anything on the winform application in the past 60 seconds, it should perfom an auto-logout action. So apart from resetting the counter on each menu, each button, etc, which is overwhelming, is there any simpler method to detect user has been inactive for 60 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this code to calculate inactivity time. It work really good, I hope it could help you too.

```
public struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint dwTime;
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern Boolean GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

/// <summary>
/// Get inactivity time
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Inactivity time in ms</returns>    
public static int GetIdleTime()
{
    LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = (UInt32)   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);

    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
    {
       UInt32 lastInputTick = lastInputInfo.dwTime;
       if (lastInputTick == 0)
          return 0;
       return (Environment.TickCount - (Int32)lastInputInfo.dwTime);
    }
    else
        return 0;
 }


 //In your method :
if (GetIdleTime() >= yourTime)
{
    //logout
}
```